# How to teach game programming at school?

Tags: teaching

I'm in this private school right now, and apart from my progressive stoppage of anti-depressants, I'm having an hard time focusing on what the school wants me to do.

The school has a professional contract for a game we have to do with Unity. I don't really learn anything new while using unity, so I don't like using it.

We recently learned how to use DirectX, and we have to do some sort of Gradius-precursor clone (Parsec) with directX, in 3D: this annoys me, and I'm currently learning to use Ogre3D by myself by making some game.

The teacher is an engineer, and all of us won't be engineers.

How would you teach game programming ?

Comment: If you're not learning anything new using Unity, you're not looking at your schooling the right way. You can learn something new from any new technology, even if it's not to your taste or seems too simplistic. However, it's good that you're working to learn other techs on your own.

Comment: I don't see the point in this question.

Comment: Unity Pro licenses? Why not make editor extensions?

Comment: Surely it doesn't matter what tool you're using, it depends on what you want to learn. If you want to learn low level graphics then you are completely entitled to use OpenGL/DirectX. If you want to learn other things like Physics and AI you can very easily learn these concepts through creating the appropriate scripts in Unity. In all honesty, the final question seems to me like you want everyone here to say "YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG" to your school, just so you can show them and that, quite frankly, just doesn't sit right with me.

Answer (score 6):

The big problem is that many people don't enjoy programming enough to warrant learning to use DirectX or OpenGL. Also you shouldn't (always) reinvent the wheel; even when using something like Ogre3D, you're a long way from having the basics of Unity implemented. It's easier to start with Unity and introduce them to Unity scripting, and they will have more fun with it.

I am of the opinion that something like Unity or Game Maker should be taught first. Game programming is basically segregated into several sub-categories: game scripting (possibly including AI scripting), engine programming, tools programming. The easiest and most fun of these is game scripting, which would be what you do in Unity, Game Maker, etc.

You are obviously more interested in engine programming (or just low-level game development, whatever category that fits in - all of them?) but I don't believe that's the universal way to teach game programming.

So to directly answer your question, **teach game programming by starting with game scripting in an existing engine and toolkit such as Unity, because this will appeal to the most people. Those that want to dive deeper (lower-level) can then be introduced to DirectX/OpenGL/Ogre3D.**

Comment: "and they will have more fun with it": I don't think it is about having fun, it is about learning to do stuff, not do stuff with stuff that makes stuff for you. I'm strongly against learning to do stuff with unity first, because this app uses a lot of stuff game devs would have liked a game editor would have been, but this kind of app just *ease* the work, it doesn't teach it. Unlike you, I think it's more important to learn things from the ground up, from scratch, then use an application like unity to see the bigger level.

Comment: For your last sentence, when learning game programming, you need to teach it as a whole, not just scripting or engine programming. Game programming has to be like an efficient and reliable toolchain so it scales best for everyone. It's better to have less cons than having too much pros which in the end will just be useless because of the cons.

Comment: Teaching game programming as a whole is just not a feasible option for most schools as it is such a large topic. That's the reason most schools task you with either a small project using OpenGL/DirectX or a large one using a stable engine. Teaching everything (graphics, physics, AI, etc) would be separate modules on their own and even then would only be an introduction to them. I think you're focusing more on reusability on flexibility than necessary at this stage "why worry about the reusable when you don't yet know what's usable?"

Comment: And no, game programming doesn't have to be an efficient and reliable toolchain when you're starting out. If you want to learn game programming, you need to make games. If you want to learn graphics programming, then code graphics stuff.

Comment: The amount of fun involved directly affects motivation. If you are stuck typing code for weeks with only a polygon on screen as a test of your "engine", you're going to abandon it. But if you can start with something like Unity and make a game or two, and THEN decide that you want to try writing it from scratch, you'll have more motivation to start and perhaps a better idea of how it should go.